# Browser refresh in asp .net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, browser, refresh

I am new to asp .net web forms and I am having trouble in efficiently handling the broswer refersh. I have used the below link to do the same.
http://geekswithblogs.net/Vipin/archive/2011/06/08/detecting-browser-refresh-from-code-behind-in-.net.aspx
However , the problem with the above approach is that the button click is throwing the below error:

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

If a web user attempts to refresh the page this pattern avoid the HTTP POST request to be resubmitted.

Just force a redirect at the end of the page that receive the posted data.

Moreover rely on session like example does is never a good practice